# How I can get Viewmodel inside composable using Hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am using hilt for dependency injection, I can't find a way to get a viewmodel inside composable directly as we can't use @AndroidEntryPoint annotation with compose, it works fine when I passed it from an activity..

Comment: Did you read [the Hilt in Compose guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject your viewModel like this

```
@Composable fun MainScreen(viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel())
```

You can see my sample project in this link for more information [github](https://github.com/mahdizareeii/JetpackComposeApp)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyVm @Inject constructor(
  private val someDep: SomeDep,
) : ViewModel() {}
```

My view - considering its fragment in this case

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MYFragment : Fragment() {
  private val viewModel: MyVm by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
      setContent {
        MYTheme {
          MyTopLevelComposableScreen(
            viewModel = viewModel
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my top level composable

```
@Composable
fun MyTopLevelComposableScreen(vm:MyVm){
}
```

or directly in the top level composable

```
    @Composable
    fun MyTopLevelComposableScreen(vm: MyVm = viewModel()){
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt

Answer (score 0):

First, implementation this module:

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07")
```

And, you can use it like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun MyLayout() {
    val vm: MyViewModel = viewModel() // @HiltViewModel
...
```

[[Android developer guideline]](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel)